# Access VBA List All Files in a folder and all of its subfolders

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im trying to create some code in Access which will loop through a folder i.e. C:\Users\ANON\LotsofSubFolders and find the most recent file in all of the subfolders that matches a specific name.

For Example, in C:\Users\ANON\Data there is a folder for this 2018, 2019... and inside each 2018 and 2019 there is another folder i.e. Jan, Feb, etc. 
I want to be able to find the most recent file named "FindFile_1.xlsx".

Example File Paths:
C:\Users\ANON\Data\2019\Jan\FindFile_1.xlsx
C:\Users\ANON\Data\2019\Feb\FindFile_1.xlsx
C:\Users\ANON\Data\2018\Dec\FindFile_1.xlsx

I have been able to use the following script to find the first subfolder i.e. 2018 or 2019, however it does not go down the next level and so on.

```
Sub GetSubFolderNames()
Dim MyFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim MyFile As File
Dim MyFolder As Folder
Dim MySubFolder As Folder

Set MyFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set MyFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\sumit\Desktop\Test")

For Each MySubFolder In MyFolder.SubFolders
    Debug.Print MySubFolder.Name
Next MySubFolder

End Sub
```

Im then faced with the challenge of trying to the find the most recent file named   xxxx once i have all of the subfolders.

Comment: This is doable, surprised nobody answered you. Did you figure this out yet?

Comment: This is not a duplicate either lol. Since you are trying to find the most recent file name.